# AWS AMI Source Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I created an AMI from an EC2 Instance,
After the AMI got created I was not able to trace it's source Instance,
**The Source under Details describes,**

"For AMIs backed by the Amazon instance store, this is the location of the Amazon S3 source manifest. For AMIs backed by Amazon EBS, this is the owner and name of the AMI."

[image]

**How would I find out the AMI's source EC2 Instance ID or Tag?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for the AMI id in Snapshot Descriptions. They say something like "Created by CreateImage(i-...) for ami-... from vol-..." where i-... is the EC2 instance id.

Comment: Thanks, found the Instance ID from which the AMI was created.